# Let $A = \mathbb{Z}$, $B = [−1, \pi]$, $C = (2, 7)$. List all elements of $A \cap (B^c \cap C)$.

Tags: proof-verification

After working it out on a number line, I got: $\{4, 5, 6\}$.

As it stands, the expression contains the integers that do not belong to the set $B$ that cross into $C$. This would result in $4, 5, 6$. Number $7$ would not be included because of the soft brackets surrounding $C = (2, 7)$. Is this correct?

Comment: By $Bc$ I assume you mean $B^\mathsf{c}$?

Comment: Indeed, $A \cap (B^c \cap C)=\mathbb{Z} \cap (\pi, 7)=\{4,5,6\}$

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín I agree with your final answer, but $B^c\cap C \neq \{4,5,6\}$. It equals the interval $(\pi, 7)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right.

Here are the intermediate steps: $B^c=(-\infty, -1) \cup (\pi, \infty)$, so $B^c\cap C = (\pi, 7)$.

And as you wrote, the only integers in that interval are $4,5,6$.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

$B^\mathsf{c} \cap C = (\pi, 7)$

$A \cap (B^\mathsf{c} \cap C) = \mathbb{Z} \cap (\pi, 7) = \{4,5,6\}$

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for all numbers

- in $\mathbb Z$; and
- in $(-\infty,-1)\cup(\pi,\infty)$; and
- in $(2,7)$.

In words, what you're looking for are

- all integers;
- that are *either* less than $-1$ *or* greater than $\pi$; and
- that are strictly between $2$ and $7$.

These numbers are $\{4,5,6\}$.